# Clean URL's with .htaccess?

Tags: .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite

How can I replace capital letters (I found it, *strtolower()* ), symbols and spaces simply, without doing it like this?

```
$url = str_replace( " ", "-", "$title");
$url1 = str_replace( "!", "", "$url");
$url2 = str_replace( "?", "", "$url1");
$url3 = str_replace( ",", "", "$url2");
$url4 = str_replace( ":", "", "$url3");
$url5 = str_replace( "'", "", "$url4");
$url6 = str_replace( ".", "", "$url5");
```

Secondly, how can I make this URL, http://www.mysite.com/index.php?id=The-house-from-Up be accessed through http://www.mysite.com/articles/The-house-from-Up using .htaccess? At the moment I just get a 500 internal server error.

Any help/guidance please! :)

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteRule ^articles/(.*)$  index.php?id=$1 [NC,L]
```

Comment: I've updated the rule, I'd got it completely the wrong way round!  Not sure what I was thinking of before...

Comment: Hmm.. I still seem to be getting the error.. 

If I go to http://wwwmysite.com/articles/this-is-an-article-url

then I get a 500 internal server error.

Comment: and if you go to  wwwmysite.com/index.php?id=this-is-an-article-url  then that works fine?

Comment: Okay, now I don't get the 500 Internal Server error but none of the content loads up...?